# Minimal proxy contract, can make pair but can’t add liquidity

Tags: erc-20, proxy-contracts, uniswapv2, liquidity, eip-1167

I have a cloneFactory which produces ERC20 compliant clones based on a master template.

I’m able to deploy my clones and even create pairs for the clones. But when I want to add liquidity (addLiquidityETH) function of the uniswapv2router or even do it manually via the uniswap interface, it doesn’t allow me.

I get the “TransactionHelper: TRANSFER_FAILED_FROM” but both programmaticly and manual they have the right approval/ allowance.

Since a clone is derived from a deployed master, its ABI and bytecode and the uniswap router does check on it in:

```
function safeTransferFrom(address token, address from, address to, uint value) internal {
        // bytes4(keccak256(bytes('transferFrom(address,address,uint256)')));
        (bool success, bytes memory data) = token.call(abi.encodeWithSelector(0x23b872dd, from, to, value));
        require(success && (data.length == 0 || abi.decode(data, (bool))), 'TransferHelper: TRANSFER_FROM_FAILED');
    }
```

Maybe it has effect on it, I don’t know anymore :) anyone has a clue?